# Can the Raspberry Pi Zero run Java 8? And on which OS image?

Tags: java, pi-zero

I'm looking to run a java 8 application on the raspberry pi zero. Which is a recommended image to use to run Java 8?

Answer (score 6):

I've been using Java 8 tools on a Raspberry Pi 2, so I see no reason why it should not work on a Zero. It won't be as snappy as on a x86_64 or even an ARM with better CPU/more RAM but it will work. I'd recommend to use Raspian because it's easy to install and maintain, `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` to get all you need to execute and compile Java programs.

Comment: And that is the big question. The Pi Zero is not just a little less powerful (single core vs. quad core of the Pi2) but has also a different architecture (ARMv6 vs. ARMv7 on the Pi2).

Comment: There are `armel` and `armhf` [packages for Debian](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/openjdk-8-jdk), so it is possible to run them. Whether it makes sense to do it is another question. But if it's possible, it should be tried :-)

Comment: Oh definitely :)

Comment: I tested Java 8 works in `Raspberry Pi 0 W` I tested here is recording https://asciinema.org/a/c7xdPAo0NIJjPXjXfu14y2sjn

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can run Java 8 on a Raspberry Pi Zero.

I have a Raspberry Pi B and B+ and Oracle Java 8 is running fine on both and is pre-installed on Raspian OS. Raspberry Pi B and B+ using the same ARMv6 architecture like the Raspberry Pi Zero. So there is no reason why it should not run on the Zero. Also the Raspberry Pi Foundation is looking after compability across the variant models.

You can also run openJDK 8 but Oracle JDK runs faster because it compiled with the hard-float ABI for ARMv6/7.